# Access denied Error when implementing facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to implement facebook Like button on my website, it's not showing on my screen, but  works well when viewed on other peoples screen. http://goo.gl/nj5UU . I also got this error in Google Chrome Inspect Element feature `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Access Denied) http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`

Please how can I make the plugin show on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be working fine. Can you once check using `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` instead of `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`?